# Get today's date from jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to change the default display of `currentText` property in jquery datepicker from "Today" to "Today: Septmeber 14, 2012". So the question is does the datepicker expose today's date via some method? or do I have to create my own JS new Date() and get the date from there, which I am trying to avoid!

```
$('#txtSelectedDate').datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        currentText: "Today: " + getTodaysDate(); // Is there such a method?
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the `currentText` is what you are looking for.

```
$('#txtSelectedDate').datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    currentText: "Today:" + $.datepicker.formatDate('MM dd, yy', new Date())  
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LgTZt/1)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was just about to add it. It would be also possible to do the formatting using plain javascript, but when you already have the datepicker in place..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to initialize the datepicker with current date, you could use:

```
$(".selector").datepicker( "option", "gotoCurrent", true );
```

And of course you have the `dateFormat` which take [a format defined here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate)

Answer (score -2):

If you need to initialize the datepicker with current date, you could use:

```
 $(".selector").datepicker( "option", "gotoCurrent", true );
```