# How to get the date in datepicker

Tags: php, jquery

is this possible to get the date from datepicker after the page was loaded?
with this code i'm getting the value when the user clicks on a date.
I would like to load the val() in a hidden input field. Even if the user didn't click the (actual) date.

```
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(){
            var selectedDate = $(this).val();
            $('input[name=date]').val(selectedDate);
        }
    });


<?php  
 if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  echo "
    <div class='form-group'>
      <form action='".setComments($conn)."' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='".$_SESSION['uid']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='date' value=''>
        <textarea id='setComment' class='form-control' name='message'>
        </textarea><br>
        <button class='btn btn-default' type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Comment</button>
      </form>
    </div>";                           
?>
```

Comment: You want to get the current date on page load? Am I understanding you correctly? If so, you can use `new Date()`

Comment: 'Even if the user didn't click the (actual) date.' do you mean a default date?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428203/get-todays-date-from-jquery-datepicker

Comment: You need to load the date in hidden field means, why you need date picker ?

Answer (score 1):

you can just use like this

```
$("#datepicker").val()
```

using that you can get your date.